# Using convertRectToView on UIImageView in CATransform3DRotate Rotated UIView

Tags: objective-c, transform, frame, subview, bounds

I have a UIImageView called `draggableImageView` that is a subview of a UIView called `tiltedView` that is tilted backwards via `CATransform3DRotate` and with perspective `transform.m34 = -1 / 400.0`. That way, when I drag `draggableImageView` around, its perspective and absolute size change so that it appears to be moving in 2-space within the `tiltedView`.

I would like to calculate the frame for `draggableImageView` within `tiltedView` but using a different coordinate system (in this case, a UIView called `viewForCoordinates` that is not tilted and encompasses the whole screen). However, using `[self convertRect:self.frame toView:self.viewForCoordinates]` from within `draggableImageView` outputs the same sized frame regardless of where within `tiltedView` my `draggableImageView` is located.

I figure using `self.frame` is more appropriate than `self.bounds` since `bounds` is agnostic to the superview while `frame` is dependent upon it. However, based upon the above, I'm guessing that `convertRect` is just converting `self.frame` agnostic of the perspective manipulation applied to `self.frame`'s superview's.

I'm not sure what code would be helpful in this case, so please let me know what code I can provide to help get this question answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this!

So I think there were two main issues:

1) When `DraggableImageView` object is touched, make sure object is indeed being touched via `if ([touch view] == self)` within `- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`

2) Convert touch location to `superview` coordinate system via `self.touchLocation = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self.superview]`.

3) Convert `DraggableImageView`'s frame from `superview` coordinate to `viewForCoordinates` coordinate system. <<< ***I think my error was that I converted from `self` rather than `superview`.***

4) If making changes to `DraggableImageView`'s frame or location based on `viewForCoordinates`, calculate changes within `viewForCoordinates`'s coordinate systemm and then convert back to `DraggableImageView`'s `superview`. <<< ***I think I forgot to do this conversion :S***